# Lower and upper bounds for height of a code trie

Tags: graph-theory, trie

> For a text with n different characters, what are the upper and lower
>   bounds on the height of the trie formed using Huffman coding?

I know those n characters will always be the leaves of the trie, but I don't know how I can find a relation between the number of leaves and the height of the trie. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean Huffman coding?

Comment: @bennofs yes, my mistake, sorry